# Update statement vs multiple update statements SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have a table

```
User
(
  id primary key,
  firstName ,
  birthDate,
  salary
)
```

I want to update all users salary to 400 with a birthDate > 2014-02-01 (for example). Which one is better for not locking, to make one update

```
Update User 
set salary = 400 
where birthDate > 2014-02-01
```

or to select all users where birthDate > 2014-02-1 to my c# code and then execute update each by each by primary key like

```
update User 
set salary = 400 
where id = xxx
```

Please explain the answer

Comment: define "better for not locking"... single update is atomic and might lock extents or the whole table, in C# version it depends on transaction isolation level, and is going to take much longer and cause more "traffic"

Comment: i mean table or page lock not to happen. i will not use any transaction level on c# side

Comment: A single row update will not lock a whole page or table ..... it will lock **just that ONE row** that it's updating. ....

Comment: It sounds that the first query is better than the second, because you'll do the query only once.  For the second one, you'll have to execute the query multiple times for each single user ID.  Of course, because the process will be for only one user ID, the second query will execute faster than the first, as opposed to the first one that will check all birthDate > 2014-02-01.

Comment: that one-row-at-a-time, transaction-less approach would trade concurrency for integrity - if you do that in multi-user scenarios, two or more such operations would race and cause inconsistent results.

Comment: What data volume are we talking about?
If you have small number of records, your worries about the locking might be totally irrelevant.

Comment: maybe you need to consider that locking alone is not something you need to avoid... rather deadlocks, and there are ways to avoid them as well (consistent order of table access etc.)

Comment: Agree dlatikay, might be that OP is trying to solve deadlocks by minimizing lock times - might get fewer deadlocks, but surely not the right solution

Comment: whichever solution you go with add 'Salary <> 400' to the where clause, there's no point locking a record by changing it to it's current value.